# How to create a condition in my web.config file for it to only affect files in the current directory

Tags: web-config

Part of my web.config file in the httpdocs directory on my website is below. It works fine for it's main purpose, which is to redirect all files with .php extension to the no-extension version. However, the contact form on my website uses a file called "mailer.php", and my form is not working properly anymore because the "mailer.php" is redirected to just "mailer". My contact form works fine when I remove the code below from the web.config file.

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>   
  <rewrite>          
    <rules>             
         <rule name="Redirecting .php ext" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*).php"/>
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*).php"/>
          </conditions>
         <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}"/>
        </rule>
    </rules>      
  </rewrite>   
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

So my question is: how can I change this code so it won't redirect the "mailer.php" to "mailer"? I would like to solve this by adding a condition so the rule only redirects files in the httpdocs directory and not any child or parent directory, since my "mailer.php" file is in a child directory.